# cairo drawing a slanted text

Tags: text, draw, cairo

```
cairo_move_to (cr, x, y);
cairo_show_text (cr, "hello");
```

You know, will draw a parallel text to the axis, but now, I want to draw a slanted text somewhat like this:

[image]

but avoid cairo_rotate,I have two point, start point and end point, Tell me how to do, thanks

Comment: "but avoid cairo_rotate" ok, then use cairo_matrix_init(), cairo_matrix_rotate() and cairo_set_matrix(). Why do you want to rotate without using cairo_rotate()?

Comment: Because I don't want to calculate the direction angle, but to draw text by    initial coordinates and destination coordinates directly.

Comment: Calculating the angle is just a call to atan2(). Does "I don't want to calculate the angle" still apply if you are given a function that gets two points as arguments and the text and then draws the text?

Comment: Thank you for your kind assistance, "calculate the angle" or atan2() means  additional expenses, you know I have a lot of texts, If I can use two points to draw text directly, It'll save me so much cpu time, but, We can't seem to do that, I will take you advice, just call atan2(), I will show you my graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cairo is [not meant](https://developer.gnome.org/cairo/stable/cairo-text.html) for that; use Pango. Other than `cairo_rotate`, you don't really have any options in Cairo. As the linked page states, Cairo has only a *toy* text API.